# Why a number cannot be "Null" in AS3.0 ?

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3.0 a variable of type Number cannot be NULL. Why is it so  ? Why the variable yet not defined, is separated as containing something called NaN  ( Not a number ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it is because of many computations you can do on Number and that they wanted to make it look different to null (undefined value is still possible btw), for instance 0 / 0 gives NaN.

NaN can't compare to any value: it gives false.
If you compute stuff with NaN, you'll get NaN: it means that if you have 'incorrect input', the computation result is: 'incorrect input' and not magical stuff produced by a dynamic evaluation on Number (for instance vanilla value for int is 0, so computation on int can give a result). So NaN has meaning.

Here is a great article about NaN usage in ActionScript 3: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/151